# visual studio 2015 editor vs visual studio code for angular 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have created data access layer ,Business access layer and web api as separate projects in one visual studio solution.

I am trying to implement angular 4 project using angular cli. Is it better for me to include angular 4 as a class library project and add to the existing solution or do I avoid adding it to the solution and just use visual studio code to open it.

I need to know which is the better code editor to use as far as angular 4 is concerned.

Comment: If your computer is powerful, I'll say Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to successfully use the Angular CLI, the VS Code would be much easier than trying to merge the result into a Visual Studio project.

Alternatively, you can use the new `dotnet new angular` and use Visual Studio's template. See this link for more information: https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/04/20/dotnet-new-angular-single-page-application-setup-and-how-the-template-works/

Most devs I know are going with option 1 and using the CLI and VS Code for the Angular piece and Visual Studio for the back-end piece.

Comment: Thanks Deborah. You have created some wonderful training courses on Plural sight and I really like it.

Comment: :-) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that nowadays both VS Code and Visual Studio 2017 offer similar experiences. You can check my blog post here for more information:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wael-kdouh/2017/09/05/should-i-use-visual-studio-2017-or-vs-code-for-my-next-angular-application/